# After pip install jupyter within a virtualenv, the Python 3 kernel is hardcoded for that virtualenv's python. How to fix?

Tags: ipython, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I switch to any other virtualenv and do a "pip install jupyter", when I run the notebook the Python 3 kernel is hardcoded to point to the python of the **initial** virtualenv that jupyter was installed in.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have [installed a kernelspec](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) from the first environment, and that's telling Jupyter to start Python 3 kernels in that environment. If you find it (`jupyter kernelspec list`) and remove it, Jupyter will default to starting kernels in the environment in which it's run. Alternatively, you can create a kernelspec for each environment where you want to run a kernel (see the link above).